# hibernate invalid configuration error

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Hi I am very new to hibernate. This is my hibernate Configuration File.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>        
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ayush.sinha.com:3306/sampledb</property>
<property name="connection.username">ayush</property>
<property name="connection.password">ayush123</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<mapping resource="com/mycompany/Contact.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
[java] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
 [java] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
 [java] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
 [java] HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
 [java] HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
 [java] HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
 [java] org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:195)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:833)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:227)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:136)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:109)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
 [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
 [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2070)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
 [java]     at Manager.main(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:218)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:153)
 [java]     ... 20 more
 [java] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:223)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
 [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
 [java]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
 [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
 [java]     ... 28 more
 [java] Java Result: -1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if anything else is required. I have displayed only the relevant parts for easy debugging

Comment: I have the closing tags.. Sorry missed it here

Comment: You conf file seems fine. lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25 match in the middle of a word... Can you recompile and repackage ?